# Writing custom 500 response body works with IIS Express, but fails on IIS ASP.Net Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.Net Core 1.0 (release) API project.
I've written a custom Exception Filter to log and return a standard error to callers.  Everything works as expected under IIS-Express.  I get the 500 response code and the custom json object.  When I deploy to an full IIS server though, I get no response.  The error is logged, but the response is never sent back to the client.  This is a mystery to me.

Here is the exception filter:

```
public async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
{
    Exception ex = context.Exception;
    string message = string.Empty;
    int incidentId = 0;

        string parameters = string.Empty;
        if (ex is NotifyingException)
        {
            parameters = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(((NotifyingException)ex).NotificationData);
        }
        incidentId = await Logger.LogIncidentAsync(context.HttpContext.Request.Path, ex, parameters);
        message = string.Format(ValidationResources.OperationFailed, incidentId);

    string msg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = message, incidentId = incidentId });
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);

    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
    await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

In startup.cs, I'm adding the filter (IncidentExceptionFilter) like this:

```
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        config.Filters.Add(new ClaimsAuthorizationFilter());
        config.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAll"));
        config.Filters.Add(typeof(IncidentExceptionFilter));
    }
    );
```

I have a simple test page that just throws an exception to test.
This is what I get using Postman when running on IIS:
[image]

Perfect.  Exactly what I expect.  Under full IIS though, Postman says: "Count not get any response".  The rest of the API works fine, and the log is written to, so it's making it into the filter, just nothing is coming out....

Comment: Weird. BTW you could just do this in your exception filter and avoid doing the writing explicitly. Give it a try and see if it fixes the issue in IIS

    var result = new JsonResult(new { message = message, incidentId = incidentId });
    result.StatusCode = 500;
    context.Result = result;

Comment: That did in fact solve the problem!  Thanks!  The mystery remains, but the problem is fixed.

Comment: Can you try one thing...before my suggested change, could you try setting the Content-Length property explicitly and see if that fixes the issue on IIS

Comment: Setting the length manually fixed it as well.
`context.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;`

Comment: Thanks for trying that out. Not sure why IIS doesn't like it without content length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kiran mentions above, I was not setting the content length.  This solved the problem.  Now both of these solutions work fine on IIS:

```
string msg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = message, incidentId = incidentId });
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);

context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
context.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

OR

```
var result = new JsonResult(new { message = message, incidentId = incidentId });
result.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
context.Result = result;
```

Which is much cleaner!